# How to print the sum of NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsnumber

i cannot find the way to print the sum of all the numbers between 0 to 100 in a new line in the console. Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *intArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= 100 ; i ++)
        [intArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
        NSLog(@"%@", intArray);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to print the sum of all the integers from 1 to 100?  How about:

```
NSLog(@"5050");
```

Comment: DarkDust What does your comment mean?

Comment: @JohnRiselvato there's an anecdote about Gauss computing this sum very quickly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Friedrich_Gauss#Anecdotes

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're even using an array here. To sum the numbers between 1 and 100 just loop through that range adding the current number to a total, then print the total out.

```
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        total += i;
    }
    NSLog(@"%i", total);
```